# jquery - capturar conteúdo de todas as divs com uma classe setada

Tags: jquery, html, loop

Tenho uma agenda que quero esconde quando todos os dias da semana estiverem fechados.
Então fiz esta função que analisa se o conteúdo do dia se é Fechado e se todos os 7 dias tiverem Fechados ele esconde a agenda.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var statusClosed = $('.agenda-status').html(); 
        if (statusClosed === 'Fechado') {
                $('.agenda-dia').addClass('dia-fechado');
                var semanaFechada = $('.agenda-semanal .dia-fechado').length;
                if( semanaFechada >= 7 ) {
                    $('.agenda-semanal').addClass('semana-fechada');
                    $('.semana-fechada').hide();
                }  
        }
});
```

Acontece que quando todos os dias da agenda estão fechados ele funciona, mas se o primeiro dia estiver aberto ele não executa a função.
Acredito que seja por conta do .html() só fazer a busca no primeiro elemento.

Como faço pra ele buscar em todos os elementos ".agenda-status" e não só no primeiro?

`<li class="agenda-dia ">
     <a href="javascript:;" data-type="Fechado">
       <span class="dia-semana Domingo">Domingo</span>
          <em class="agenda-status">Fechado</em>
</a></li>`

Comment: Você pretende esconder a propria agendar quando o dia for encerrado? Recomendo que poste sua pergunta em português, para que seja mais facilmente compreendida. :p

Comment: Paulo, coloquei em portugues =), obrigada. Pretendo esconder a agenda quando todos os dias (7) estiverem com o conteúdo da div  <em class="agenda-status">Fechado</em> Fechado.

Comment: Pode descrever melhor sobre como foram estruturada essas agendas? É uma agenda feita com exatamente 7 dias? Existem outras agendas semanais na página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo meu compreendimento da situação, o primeiro passo para a solução será pegar todos os elementos com a classe "*agenda-dia*" e itera-los tentando obter individualmente o status de cada um. Ex:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 var dias = $('.agenda-dia');
 var agendaStatus = [];

  $.each(dias, function() {
      var status = $(this).find('a .agenda-status').html();

      if (status == 'Fechado') {
          agendaStatus.push(this);
      }

      if (agendaStatus.length == dias.length) {
          $('.agenda-semanal').addClass('semana-fechada');
          $('.semana-fechada').fadeOut('slow');
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="agenda-semanal">
    <li class="agenda-dia ">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="Fechado">
            <span class="dia-semana Domingo">Domingo</span>
            <em class="agenda-status">Fechado</em>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="agenda-dia ">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="Fechado">
            <span class="dia-semana Segunda">Segunda</span>
            <em class="agenda-status">Fechado</em>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Abaixo há referencias interessantes sobre a solução:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
- https://api.jquery.com/find/
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement